# Restrict Mongoose return data after fields

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Is there any way to restrict my returning data after calling the method data.save() which currently returning me all the data in the collection. 
NOTE: Am using mongoose for Mapping

Comment: Not with `save()`, but `save()` really is not the best method to use anyway. You could be more specific by showing what you are attempting to do. Also MongoDB is a "database" and Mongoose is the ODM. No ORM here since the `'R'` stands for "relational", which this is not.

Comment: You clearly read the comment but instead of adding the useful information you were asked to you chose simply to remove the term ORM? You need to show what you are actually doing be that `let widget = new Widget(); widget.save()` or whatever and what you actually expect to receive as a returned result. That was what you should have done rather than the edit that you did, since adding that would get you an answer.